# UFT does not click in the webtable

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am having an issue with UFT. I have a webtable. I recorded the webtable and then dragged the webtable from OR to the editor.

Then I modified as following. Cell 1 and Cell 2 return the correct data. Inside the cells, I have only texts.

```
cell1 = Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").GetCellData(2,1)
print cell1
cell2 = Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").GetCellData(3,1)
print cell2

Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").ChildItem(2, 1, "WebElement",0).click

set objLink =Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").ChildItem(2, 1, "WebElement",0)
objLink.Click

set objLink =Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").ChildItem(2, 1, "Link",0)
objLink.Click
```

It is finding the webtable and returning the data but not clicking the row. How can I click the First row in the webtable?

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of that webtable here?

Comment: Did any of the solutions provided work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually have not tried them. I had a simply workaround and luckily that worked.  Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").Cell(2,1,).Click.  I am going to mark it as solved. I made a note of your answer in my end. I will have to give a try later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you need to be sure that the cell(2,1) of the webtable has a link in it. For that, check for the object's existence:

```
set objLink =Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").ChildItem(2, 1, "Link",0)
msgbox objLink.Exist(2)
```

If it returns `True`, then we are good to move ahead.

---

Try changing the **ReplayType** setting to `2` during the runtime as below:

```
set objLink =Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").ChildItem(2, 1, "Link",0)
setting.webpackage("replayType") = 2      'Runs mouse operations using the mouse. It will move the mouse pointer physically to the position where click will be performed
objLink.highlight
objLink.click
setting.webpackage("replayType") = 1      'Changing back to Event. Runs mouse operations using browser events.
```

You can also manually change the replayType Setting from here: Tools > Options > Gui Testing > Web > Advanced > Run Settings > Replay Type

---

If that doesn't work, **you can fire the Click Event on the Link object** as shown below:

```
set objLink = Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").ChildItem(2, 1, "Link",0)
objLink.highlight
objLink.fireevent "onclick"
```

---

Even if that doesn't work, you can try the following method(not recommended though, but if we do the calculations correctly, it will work). We try to find the position somewhere **on** the object and perform the **MouseClick** operation at that position.

```
set objLink = Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").ChildItem(2, 1, "Link",0)
objLink.highlight

Set mobj = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
x = objLink.getRoProperty("abs_x")              'x-axis: Returns the position in pixels from the Top left corner of your monitor screen(not the parent object)
y = objLink.getRoProperty("abs_y")              'y-axis: Returns the position in pixels from the Top left corner of your monitor screen(not the parent object)
h = objLink.getRoProperty("height")             'returns height of the link object in pixels
w = objLink.getRoProperty("width")              'returns width of the link object in pixels

mobj.MouseClick Cint(x+h/4),Cint(y+w/4),1       'Try playing with the denominator 4. If you set it 2, it will attempt to click on the middle of the object.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just click Row by getting TR element

```
RowNum=1 'The Row Number you want to click

'if the event handled over TR element then use without Replaytype =2
     Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").WebElement("Html tag:=TR","Index:=" & RowNum-1).Click

'otherwise use with ReplayType = 2
     Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
     Browser("Create").Page("Create").WebTable("First").WebElement("Html tag:=TR","Index:=" & RowNum-1).Click
```